# Genereic struct c++ (unresolved external symbol)

Tags: c++, generics, struct

I have a generic class which in I also have a struct. Like this:

```
template <class T> class Octree
{
    public:

    struct node
    {
        typename  T value;
        node *child[8];
    };

    Octree();
    template <class T> Octree();
    ~Octree();
    void clear(T t);

    node* root;
};
```

the .cpp file :

```
template <class T>
Octree<T>::Octree()
{
    root = new node;
    root->value = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        root->child[i] = 0;
}

template <class T>
Octree<T>::~Octree()
{
    clear(root);
}
```

and the main:

```
using namespace std;

int main() {
    Octree <int> fasz;
    Octree <char> fasz2;
    return 0;
}
```

I've just created an object of my tree and I got this error:

> Error  LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall Octree::Octree(void)" (??0?$Octree@H@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function _main Zz  c:\Users....Source.obj

I have tried to write the template declaration in a header file, then implement the class in an implementation file (for example .cpp), and include this implementation file at the end of the header but then I've got an error:

> Error  C2995   'Octree::Octree(void)': function template has already been defined

I have seen this link question but it's not what I need.

Have you any idea what the problem is?

Comment: That duplicate, and this answer as well; http://stackoverflow.com/a/12574417/3747990. You need to have the template implementations available at the time of instantiation (when it is used).

Comment: You also have a syntax issue; `template <class T> Octree();`, should just be `Octree();` in the class definition.

Comment: FYI, in C++ it's generally called _templates_, not generics.

Comment: @Niall Thank you for the answer but when I copy that : `Octree<T>::Octree() {}` on the bottom of the header then I got the same error:
 `Error C2995 'Octree::Octree(void)': function template has already been defined`

Comment: Add some include guards (or a `#pragma once`) to avoid multiple inclusions.

Comment: @Niall Now I got a new error for the closing `}` of the constructor. 
`Error C2244 'Octree<T>::Octree': unable to match function definition to an existing declaration ` Could you please help with this?

Comment: Did you remove the `template <class T> Octree();` in the class definition?

Comment: Yes I did. Should I edit the quesiton?